# Unable to find and locate the "Third-party data sources card"

Tags: google-workspace-for-business, g-suite-administrator

I am trying to create my own custom Google Cloud Search and following [this documentation](https://support.google.com/a/answer/9043922). I need to add a data source through the G Suite Admin console. I login to my Admin console I go through the first step following the path Apps > G Suite > Cloud Search > Search Settings but nothing shows up or exists on Settings window. I am unable to find and locate the "Third-party data sources card". PS. Its a brand new G Suite Domain, fresh and clear.

Anyone with prior experience on this that can help me to find out where that card is?

Comment: If you read any of the tags you have included you will see that your question is off-topic on [su]

Comment: Hi david, I was not aware of the migration from super user. My apologies, do I need to remove the post?

Comment: No. Just leave it.

Comment: @DavidPostill can I migrate it back to superuser ? or can I post it there too?

Comment: It's off-topic on [su]. That's why it was migrate here where it is on-topic.

Answer (score 0):

I think you need to be whitelisted first to be able to use this new feature. You should contact Google for that.

Answer (score 0):

You will need to sign up [here](https://cloud.google.com/products/search/) to get access.

If you have a reseller you will need to contact them to go via the cloudsearch partner team. Your G Suite or GCP reseller can find out more information on the [[Cloud Search] Partners FAQs](https://docs.google.com/document/d/1FWARyj_Q47QbZDiskobQ_2SAJ0RCyC9DYZwhBCJ4C6Q/edit) doc.